# Mo webApplication Context found and no contextloder and

Tags: spring, spring-security

I havge configured the spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginPage" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

            <logout logout-success-url="/errorPage" logout-url="//errorPage"/>
            <session-management invalid-session-url="/home?invalid=true" />
        </http>
```

and I have added the the following code in web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And then I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
```

can any one tell whts wrong with this?

Comment: I would guess that the error message is correct? You are missing `ContextLoadrListener` in your `web.xml`. Where are you loading your `spring-security.xml`?

Comment: means?....In web-inf directory

Answer (score 0):

You have your context XML file, that is fine. But you also need to somehow tell Spring to load that file. For ROOT context (which is where security config belongs) this is done by the following configuration in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>    
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>    
</listener>    
<context-param>    
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>    
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>    
</context-param>
```

Please check the [official documentation on this topic](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-create) as well.

Comment: yes I tried above solution and now getting this error: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator

Comment: You are missing `spring-aop` dependency. Check the list of libraries required by Spring Security - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/appendix-dependencies.html